# Problems Animating background color of navigation on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, so I have a navigation menu on my site and I can't seem to get this code to work when I hover over an item on the menu. I tried two codes:

code 1:

```
$("#nav li").hover(function() {
  $(this).animate({backgroundColor: "#ffffff"}, 'slow');
});
```

code 2:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#nav li").hover(
   function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({backgroundColor: "#ffffff"}, "slow");
   },
   function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({backgroundColor: "#09c"}, "slow");
   });

 });
```

This is my css, just giving this in case:

```
#nav {
margin-left:380px;
float:left;
width:650px;
margin-top:-47px;
}

#nav ul {
list-style-type:none;
}

#nav ul li {
float:left;
}

#nav ul li a {
text-align:center;
border-right:1px solid #fff;
display:block;
text-decoration:none;
color:#fff;
padding:20px;
}

#nav ul li ul {
display:none;
}

#nav ul li:hover ul {
display:block;
position:absolute;
background:#fff;
}

#nav ul li a:hover {
display:block;
background:#fff;
color:#09c;
}
```

BTW, I have also included the jQuery JavaScript Library v1.9.1 to the site (Not sure if this will be useful to you)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include jquery color plugin to animate colors.

here : http://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color-2.1.1.min.js

Indeed this feature is not supported by JQuery base lib.

Note than `.css('backgroundColor','#333333')`works but not the equivalent animation so you can test your code with css() before try it with animation() before link plugin to your page.

Comment: But I didn't quite understand what you mean in your last paragraph

Comment: It's just a note. You can change color in JQuery with [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/), no need plugin. But if you want to [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) then the plugin is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

please try below css code for change navigation menu background color

```
#nav ul li a:hover {
 background-color:#ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS3 transitions for achieving this effect, this would be more convenient.
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/css-fundametals-css-3-transitions/

Comment: This is pretty amazing, I never heard about it before. Thanks for the new technique